# Bisimulation symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, logic

Very simple question: I'm looking for the symbol that indicates that two worlds from 2 different Kripke-models are *bisimilar*, that there is a *bisimulation* between those two.

In most articles a left-right-arrow with a line below is used.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have some references, where the symbol can be seen?

Comment: detexify suggests \leftrightarroweq for which you have to \usepackage{ stmaryrd }

Comment: @Bort: Will you add an answer?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I would, but I cant. I think duplicate-marking is sufficiently anyway